# Speeding up Image Resizing

Tags: php, image, performance, gd

Problem: Script seems to be running slow. This script is inside a function that is run four times for different image sizes. Is there any way to speed up the code below?

```
$outputFile = "../data/assets/temp.jpg";
$maxTempWidth  = 45;
$maxTempHeight = 45;
$image_info = getimagesize($setXsmallNewName);

if($image_info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg'){
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($setXsmallNewName);
}elseif($image_info['mime'] == 'image/gif'){
$image = imagecreatefromgif($setXsmallNewName);
}elseif($image_info['mime'] == 'image/png'||$image_info['mime'] == 'image/x-png'){
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($setXsmallNewName);
}

$width = imagesx( $image );
$height = imagesy( $image );

if ($width > $maxTempWidth || $height > $maxTempHeight){   
    if ( $width > $height ){
        $newwidth = $maxTempWidth;
        $ratio = $maxTempWidth / $width;
        $newheight = floor($height * $ratio);

        if ($newheight > $maxTempHeight){
            $newheight = $maxTempHeight;
            $ratio = $maxTempHeight / $height;
            $newWidth = floor($width * $ratio);
        }
    }else{
        $newheight = $maxTempHeight;
        $ratio = $maxTempHeight / $height;
        $newwidth = floor($width * $ratio);

        if ($newwidth > $maxTempWidth){
            $newwidth = $maxTempWidth;
            $ratio = $maxTempWidth / $width;
            $newheight = floor($height * $ratio);
        }
    }
}else{
    $newwidth = $width;
    $newheight = $height;
}   
$final_image = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($final_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
```

Comment: That is *really* hard to believe. Are you 100% sure? If that is the bottleneck, something must be wrong

Comment: It seemed that getimagesize was the slow part, but I also think it may be the way I'm resizing the images. Updated the post with more information.

Comment: `imagecopyresampled()` is the slowest function in this code, 44% of the total execution time, but it seems to be normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), which is core to the php family and very speedy.

Comment: GD's functions are in compiled, C-based libraries too - ImageMagick may be somewhat faster (and has a bunch of other upsides) but it won't necessarily be that much.

Comment: All I'm saying is that using it will obviate the need for much of your syntax (because everything's built-in).

Comment: It seems like there has to be a way to speed up the image resizing part of this rather than switching libraries.